# Unable to find my XML field in Java

Tags: java, xml

EDIT: I guess my question wasn't clear enough. How do I access the Obligations field in my xml file and return it as a string in java?
As the title states, I have been fighting with this XML parsing issue for 2 days. I will give a snippet of my XML and of my code that I've tried.

XML:

```
 <aircraft name="Hawk">
     <AAgent/>
     <capabilities file="hawk.xml"/>
     <Obligations file="HawkO.xml"/>
     <Restrictions file="HawkR.xml"/>
     <Negotiation file="HawkN.xml"/>
  </aircraft>
```

Java to access the Obligations file:

```
if (AssetElement.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase(assetName)) { // works
    NodeList policies = AssetElement.getChildNodes();

    System.out.println("Policies nodes " + policies.toString());
    String oblig = AssetElement.getAttribute("Obligations file");
    System.out.println("Oblig = " + oblig);
    NodeList nl = AssetElement.getChildNodes();
    Node node = nl.item(2);
    System.out.println("1" + node.getNodeValue());
    System.out.println("2" + node.getNodeName());
    System.out.println("3" + node.getNodeValue());
    System.out.println("4" + node.getTagName());
    System.out.println("5" + node.getTextContent());
    System.out.println("Content" + AssetElement.getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getTextContent());
    System.out.println("Content 2" + AssetElement.getElementsByTagName("Obligations file").item(0));
    System.out.println("Name = " + AssetElement.getFirstChild().getNodeName());
    System.out.println("Value = " + AssetElement.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

}
```

As you can see I am troubleshooting this with print statement after print statement. None of them have been useful so far. This is my output to all those print statements:

```
1

2#text
3

5

Content
Content2null
Name = #text
Value =
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: What issues are you facing exactly?

Comment: How do I access the Obligations field in my xml file and return it as a string in java?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
 assetElement.getChild("Obligations").getAttributeValue("file");
```